# How to surely refer to global objects in a class during definition?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

While defining a class, I need to **set a global function (say, abc) as default arg value** on a method. Usually, its just trivial to refer to them as abc.

But problem here is that abc is itself set as a classmethod on that class. So, the 
**usual soln doesnt work** as **abc refers to "abc, the classmethod"** during class definition when "abcd" is being created. One soln might be to re-order things such that the classmethod defn. comes at the last, but I need a sure-shot (order-agnostic) way of **refering to the global abc** there.

There is only one crude way of doing it, that I know of, **using globals()["abc"]**. I want to know if theres a better way of tackling this problem.

```
def abc(cls,a=1):
    print a+1


class A(object):
    abc=classmethod(abc)
    @classmethod
    def abcd(cls,func=abc):
        pass

from inspect import getargspec
getargspec(A.abcd).defaults[0] #should be "abc" the function, not "abc" classmethod
```

Possible (but not so good ?) soln

`def abcd(cls,func=globals()["abc"])`

**Edit:**

Also, do you think globals() is quite slow?

Comment: What happens if you move the `abcd` function _before_ `abc = classmethod(abc)`?

Comment: The only way to be sure is to use `globals` as you did.  The better way of handling it is to use different names for the two things.

Comment: @mgilson It solves the problem, but I need a order-agnostic way.

Comment: @bendtherules -- Why?  I'm not really seeing the reason why that would be the case...

Comment: @BrenBarn Using two different names breaks the pattern I need to do, which is provide both global func and class method for the same purpose. Think of __providing__ (it is not there) both ways of finding the length of a string `len(str)` and `str.len()`.

Comment: Why not just rename the module level `abc`? This would have the added benefit of generally reducing ambiguity anyway.

Comment: @bendtherules: There is no `str.len()`, only `str.__len__()`.

Comment: @JoelCornett It was just an exmaple. I am trying to do it for a user-defined class. Also, renaming module level abc wont solve the case, will it?

Comment: @mgilson why for what? The order-agnostic requirement? Because it would be nice to write the class methods without caring about the previously defined methods.

Comment: @bendtherules: You still haven't given any real reason for: A) needing the global function to have the same name as the classmethod; B) needing it to work for any order.  If you remove either of those requirements, the solution is easy, so if you don't want to do that, you should have a reason for making things hard on yourself.

Comment: @BrenBarn A: Take the str.len for example. This code is supposed to be for a library-ish thing, so think of yourself as a user. Would you prefer to write code like  `len(str)` or `str.len()`, given both options? I think the __second__ one is a huge win, because of multiple reasons.
B: It would make writing the (library) code easier for me.

Comment: @bendtherules: If you think the first is better, why are you providing the second one too?

Comment: @BrenBarn Sorry, I meant the 2nd one.

Comment: @bendtherules: Same thing though.  If you think the second is better, why are you providing the first one?

Comment: I hate to invoke the Zen of Python, but "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it."

Comment: @BrenBarn Ok, here's why I need both options: 

This func should be usable __as decorator__ both __during class definition__ of say, class A(as `@abc`, which calls global abc) and __outside class__ (`@A.abc`, which calls classmethod abc). 

Inside class definition of A, `@A.abc` is ofcourse not available. But outside class definition, `@A.abc` feels more natural than `@abc(A)`

Comment: @JoelCornett Sometimes you have to be break the zen for usability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap `abc` and similar use case options in their own namespace, like so

```
class A:
    @staticmethod
    def abc(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        pass
```

Then you can refer to them cleanly

```
class Foo:
    abc = classmethod(A.abc)

    @classmethod
    def abcd(cls, fn=A.abc):
        pass
```

And order is not important.

You could also consider these workarounds:

Avoid name collisions:

```
def _abc(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    pass

class Foo:
    abc = classmethod(_abc)

    @classmethod
    def abcd(cls, fn=_abc):
        pass
```

Do all affected defs outside of class:

```
def abc(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    pass

def abcd(cls, fn=abc):
    pass

class Foo:
    abc = classmethod(abc)
    abcd = classmethod(abcd)
```

Comment: Soln. 2 would be a nightmare to maintain, because in my case, classes can have a lot of such methods.
Soln. 1 is much better, except that you would still have to remember doing that. If there are a lot of such funcs, it will still start to become manual job. Not that its any more maintainable than soln. 2, but usually no. of functions similar to `abc` would be relatively less in my case.

Comment: I understand your reasoning for wanting to do `foo(x)` and `x.foo()` in terms of instance methods, but I don't understand the use case for having `classmethods` that do that.

Comment: Because when you can get away with classethods (the func abc dont at all need a instance to work, it just operates on the class), why should you use instancemethods. Classmethods are more flexible in the sense that you can call both A.abc and A().abc (where A is the class).

Comment: @bendtherules: Why not just `staticmethod` then? AFAIK `classmethod` is used when you *need* a reference to the class inside the function definition.

Comment: As I wrote in my earlier comment, yes it needs access to the class.

Comment: Cool, great one. 3rd option solves my problem in the least-obstructive way. Thanks.

Comment: @bendtherules: NP, I'm rearranging my answer slightly to clarify which solution you found helpful.

Comment: Ran into a few problem using the staticmethod approach when functions started to increase and one func starts depending on another. Say func B calls func A and both are defined in this class Utils, so in class code, func A should be put before B. So, you use `cls.A` which means you need to set it classmethod. Now, when your funcs starts becoming classmethods, things get more complicated. You cant just call `Utils.B` now, need to do `Utils.B.im_func`. Suddenly, you need to refer to some as `Utils.func_name.im_func` and some as `Utils.func_name`, purely depending on if they call other funcs.

Comment: @bendtherules: You can substitute the class for a module. That should solve your problem, while preserving namespacing.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way:

```
def abc(cls,a=1):
    print a+1


class A(object):
    @classmethod
    def abcd(cls,func=abc):
        pass

A.abc=classmethod(abc)
```

It's up to you whether this is "better" than using `globals`.

Comment: Its just similar suggestion as putting classmethod defn at the last. It would be nice to have it defined within the class in a order-agnostic way, although Im not sure if its possible.